# Change Ajax from onclick to onsubmit

Tags: ajax

I would like to change the following code, at the moment the code reads data from the input box of an ajax table (seven script - ajax table editor) then when you click save it adds it to the table. I would like it so it does this when the user presses enter, how can I do this by modifying the code:

```
if(editTblRow==null && editTblCell==null){
if(fieldtype!='blob'){
$($('#ajaxtb')[0].rows[rowid].cells[cellid]).html('<input type="text" id="edit_box" class=\"edit_input\" value=\"' + id + '\" /><div class=\"cell_opts\"><a href=\"javascript:return false;\" onclick=\"' + "editCell('','','','','','save','','" + updatestring + "');" + '\">Save</a> - <a href=\"javascript:return false;\" onclick=\"' + "editCell('','','','','','cancel');" + '\">Cancel</a></div>'); 

} else {

$($('#ajaxtb')[0].rows[rowid].cells[cellid]).html('<textarea id="edit_box" class=\"edit_input\" value=\"' + id + '\" >' + id + '</textarea> <div class=\"cell_opts\"><a href=\"javascript:return false;\" onclick=\"' + "editCell('','','','','','save','','" + updatestring + "');" + '\">Save</a> - <a href=\"javascript:return false;\" onclick=\"' + "editCell('','','','','','cancel');" + '\">Cancel</a></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this JQuery function. It will help identify if the enter key is clicked.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
   if(e.which == 13) {
     // Your code here
   }
});
```